# Possible to override using spring profiles without setting explicit default profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Imagine I had the following beans defined in `beans.xml`:

```
<beans>   
  <bean id=“myBean1”  class=“foo.Bar”>
    <property name=“prop1” value=“abc”/> 
    <property name=“prop2” value=“def”/>
  </bean>   
  <bean id=“myBean2”  parent=“myBean1” />   
  <bean id=“myBean3”  parent=“myBean2” /> 
</beans>

<beans profile=“testProfile”>   
  <bean id=“myBean1”  class=“foo.Bar”>
    <property name=“prop1” value=“ghi”/>
  </bean> 
</beans>
```

If I had a class using `myBean1` with `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=testProfile`, would it have `prop1=ghi` and `prop2=def`?

What if the class was using `myBean1` with `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=` (empty)? Would it just use the definition of `myBean1` defined in the first `beans` block without a defined profile? Or would it cause an error?

If I set `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=testProfile` and use `myBean2` or `myBean3`, should I expect the property override in `testProfile` to take effect such that `prop1=ghi` in either of these beans when `testProfile` is set?

Do I need to set a profile of `!testProfile` somewhere to accomplish this, and if so, how does that affect inheritance for child beans of `myBean1`?

I am interested in whether there is a way to implement this that is purely "opt-in" so that I can avoid having to modify the existing default definition of `myBean1` and its children when I want to provide optional properties via a profile.

I am using spring version 4.3.21

Comment: Boot will automatically set `default` if _no profile at all_ is turned on, and you can use `!test` to invert the condition.

Comment: When using profiles with bean definitions it will just override the other one, it won't merge them. So no it will not have value `ghi` and `def` for the properties.